# Altering max-execution-time on a per module basis

Tags: 7

I have some components (mass XML/CSV import) where we may need to set the PHP Max Execution Time beyond a 30 second cap. Is there a way I can lift this restriction on module-specific logic (with `ini_set()` for example) over having to force it inside a php.ini setting?

Before you ask -- yes, I know making this logic a Drush command would be better suited for this, but the nature of our host not providing SSH makes it difficult for us to install or use Drush.

Comment: Are you looking for [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)?

Comment: I think the Drupal specific wrapper for that, `drupal_set_time_limit()` could work.

Comment: Never come across that one before, it would be worth putting an answer to that effect in. The caveat is that the Drupal version fails silently if the hosting company have disabled `set_time_limit`, so it might not actually do anything

Comment: I'm going to test it on my Staging environment tonight, and if it works, I will definitely mark it as an answer.